# Using an Array to check PivotItems.Name <> Array Then PivotItems.Visible = False

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use an array to check the filtered pivot items in the pivot table to see if it should be visible or not. Currently I have it hard coded with the code below. However, I would like to use an Array when I have more then one item to check against the filter.

The goal is to only filter on the items needed.

```
Supply = Array("X Marketplace", "Y Marketplace")

With PivFid
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        If .PivotItems(i).Name <> "X Marketplace" Then .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i
End With
```

This is something I am trying to accomplish but I'm not sure how to loop through the array against the filtered items.

```
With PivFid
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        If .PivotItems(i).Name <> Supply Then .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Will you also need to *Unhide* items?

Comment: No need for unhiding any items for this. @TimWilliams

Comment: Please be aware that ALWAYS at least 1 pivotitem has to remain visible. Worst case: If the last item is invisible and should be the only visible one, the you'll get an error at the second last item, as in this short moment every item is invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.Match` to check it. Combined with `IsError` in front of it, it will check if a current `PivotItem` name is not found within the entire `Supply` array).

**Code**

```
Supply = Array("X Marketplace", "Y Marketplace")

With PivFid
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        If IsError(Application.Match(.PivotItems(i).Name, Supply, 0)) Then .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
    Next i
End With
```

**Just in case** you need to show the other ones:

```
With PivFid
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        If IsError(Application.Match(.PivotItems(i).Name, Supply, 0)) Then
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Else
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @Shai Rado! This is exactly what I'm looking for.